# How to avoid Binary Translator on Intel Atom Android devices?

Tags: android, x86

I'm running my app on a tablet with Intel processor (Acer Iconia Tab 8), and when I read /proc/cpuinfo from within my app I get that the CPU it's an ARMv7. Is this because the tablet is using the Binary Translator for executing my app? Can I execute my app in x86 native mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the Acer tablet Android version. It was executing the binary translator for every app. After an update, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an x86 native version of your app by editing your Application.mk file to modify the APP_ABI variable like so:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi x86
```

That's it, but if you want more details, [Intel has a writeup](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/adding-support-for-x86-architecture).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's correct, but it was an Acer issue.